# transmission torrent won't reconnect to data folder

Tags: downloads, bittorrent, transmission

I was about 90% through downloading a torrent when I needed to do a reboot. When I turned the computer back on and went back into Transmission to resume downloading I got the message:

**Error no data found! Ensure your drives are connected or use "set location"**

I'm not sure why this happened as the drives were never physically disconnected, but maybe perhaps I launched Transmission before they were mounted. In an attempt to fix this, I restarted the computer and allowed the drives to mount before starting Transmission, but I still got the same error about the missing data.

In attempt to fix this, I tried the following:

Right clicking the torrent in Transmission, then clicking "**Set Location**", selecting '**data is already there**' radio button, and then navigating to the folder where the data is. (I made sure I pointed Transmission to the parent directory where the data was downloading to. To double check where Transmission thought the data was, I right clicked the torrent in Transmssion, went to properties, and looked at LOCATION, which showed exactly where I told it to set the folder to.

After setting the location to where the files were I right clicked on the torrent and clicked '**Verify Local Data**', but nothing seemed to happen after that and the error remained.

I also did the above actions with **'Move Data File To'** the location, with no results either.

STILL NO LUCK.

So, the only thing I can think of at this opint is something I read on another site about the files. Someone mentioned that if I did not download **ALL** the files set out in the torrent file, that Transmission might think it's not the same when trying to reconnect. In my case when I was prompted to choose which files I wanted to download from the torrent, I did not choose everything (omitting to download some files).

Could this be the reason this is not working? Is there another way to make this work without having to re-download the whole thing (this is a **100 gig+** torrent, and I dont want to lose my ratio, and time spent getting the files).

Using Transmission v.2.82 (14160) on Ubuntu 14.04

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

No promises, but the following worked for me:

- Right-click the torrent, then select Copy Magnet Link to Clipboard
- Right-click the torrent, then select Remove
- Click Remove
- File -> Open URL
- Click Open
- Click Open again
- Right-click the newly (re)created torrent, then select Verify Local Data

Good luck.

Comment: it worked, even after moving files from original folder to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me also!

I´ve downloaded the torrent file and added in Transmission linux path to that file rather than the .torrent (with "start when added" option uncheck).

Than:

- click "Set Location" to point to your directory on computer;
- click "Verify local data"